# Action on endpoint /logout for JWT with refresh tokens

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, authorization, refresh-token

I used access token (JWT - expire after 10 minutes) and refresh token (expire after 24 hours) to authorization service running in a few cleints (mobile / web.. ).

I want to implement **/logout** endpoint and pass refresh token as query/path variable to delete refresh token from db and the same way disable possibility to create new access tokens only from one client.

Is good way?
How should works endpoint **/logout**.?

Second way is delete all refresh token by user-id (from access token) but then we loss access from every clients (web / mobile..) and it is bad use case.

Thank you for all the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a standards compliant token revocation endpoint to revoke the refresh token and/or access token as specified in [RFC 7009 OAuth2 .0 Token Revocation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7009)